# Contact form not typing on mobile

Tags: html, css, contact-form

My contact form doesn't seem to work on any mobile devices. It works on PC but when i try it on any mobile or ipad, I can't get to type any info into de fields.

My code looks like this :::::

```
<form id="form-contacto" action="contacto.php" method="post" />
        <div id="clientes">
        <h3>Cliente</h3>
        <div>
                <label>            
                    <input class="form_col" type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre">
                </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                <label>
                    <input class="form_col" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                <label>                         
                    <input class="form_col" type="tel" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono">
                </label>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div id="planes">
        <h3>Planes</h3>
        <div class="select">
                <label>
                <span class="form">Branding</span>
                      <select name="branding" id="branding" class="form-select">
                        <option value="0"></option>
                        <option value="Básico">Básico</option>
                        <option value="Plus">Plus</option>
                        <option value="A su medida">A su medida</option>
                      </select>
                </label>
        </div>
        <div class="select">
                <label>
                    <span class="form">Corporativo</span>
                      <select name="corporativo" id="corporativo" class="form-select">                              
                        <option value="0"></option>
                        <option value="Emprendedor">Emprendedor</option>
                        <option value="Plus">Plus</option>
                        <option value="A su medida">A su medida</option>
                      </select>
                </label>
        </div>
        <div class="select">
                <label>
                    <span class="form">Web</span>
                      <select name="web" id="web" class="form-select">                              
                        <option value="0"></option>
                        <option value="Básico">Básico</option>
                        <option value="Plus">Plus</option>
                        <option value="Responsive">Responsive</option>
                        <option value="A su medida">A Su medida</option>
                      </select>
                </label>
        </div>
        </div> -->
        <div id="proyecto">
        <h3>Proyecto</h3>
        <div class="columnas">
                <label>
                      <select name="servicios" id="servicios" class="form-select">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione el área de servicio</option>
                        <option value="Diseño Gráfico">Diseño Gráfico</option>
                        <option value="Diseño Web">Diseño Web</option>
                        <option value="Producción Audiovisual">Producción Audiovisual</option>
                      </select>
                </label>
        </div>
        <div class="columnnas">
                <label>
                    <textarea name="descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción del proyecto"></textarea>
                </label>
        </div>
        <div id="bt_enviar">
                    <button id="enviar" type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it is because you don't respect the hmtl standard. Input never goes in a label, neither any form element (select, textarea). `<label>my label</label> <input type="text" />`.